# JPA/Hibernate5: How to replace a child object mapped with @OneToOne and @MapsId?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a bidirectional @OneToOne association between Parent and Child entities, with @MapsId to share the primary key.

With a Parent object, I can add a Child, remove it, then add a new Child object:

```java
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.name = "parent";
        Child child = new Child();
        child.name = "child";
        child.parent = parent;
        parent.child = child;
        manager.persist(parent);
        manager.flush();

        // Replace this block with ?
        parent.child = null;
        child.parent = null;
        manager.persist(parent);
        manager.flush();

        Child child2 = new Child();
        child2.name = "child2";
        child2.parent = parent;
        parent.child = child2;
        manager.persist(parent);
```

But, **is there a way to set a new Child object without removing (and flushing) the old one?**

If I remove the `flush()` from the middle block, Hibernate complains the identifier is already associated with the session. I guess I'm looking for a way to tell Hibernate to ignore the old Child entity, allow the new one to have the same id, and run an SQL update for the new Child instead of insert.

I realize I can just update the current Child fields, but I would like to know if a full object replacement is possible.

The full code showing Entity definitions is here:

```java
import javax.persistence.*;

public class OneToOneExample {

    @Entity(name = "Parent")
    public static class Parent {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        Long id;

        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        Child child;

        String name;
    }

    @Entity(name = "Child")
    public static class Child {
        @Id
        Long id;

        @OneToOne
        @MapsId
        Parent parent;

        String name;
    }

    private static void runExample(EntityManager manager) {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.name = "parent";
        Child child = new Child();
        child.name = "child";
        child.parent = parent;
        parent.child = child;
        manager.persist(parent);
        manager.flush();

        // Replace this block with ?
        parent.child = null;
        child.parent = null;
        manager.persist(parent);
        manager.flush();

        Child child2 = new Child();
        child2.name = "child2";
        child2.parent = parent;
        parent.child = child2;
        manager.persist(parent);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = null;
        EntityManager manager = null;
        try {
            factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(OneToOneExample.class.getPackageName());
            manager = factory.createEntityManager();
            manager.getTransaction().begin();
            runExample(manager);
            manager.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            if (manager != null) manager.close();
            if (factory != null) factory.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [....OneToOneExample$Child#1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:733)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:695)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:492)
    at ...
```

I am using Hibernate 5.4.6.Final, Hibernate-JPA2.1 1.0.2.Final, HSQLDB 2.5.0

**Update:** original Hibernate SQL generation and table data:

```sql
Hibernate: drop table if exists Child CASCADE 
Hibernate: drop table if exists Parent CASCADE 
Hibernate: drop sequence hibernate_sequence if exists
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
Hibernate: create table Child (name varchar(255), parent_id bigint not null, primary key (parent_id))
Hibernate: create table Parent (id bigint not null, name varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table Child add constraint FKlh67j1n7x7gt59u0pbkwqh6o6 foreign key (parent_id) references Parent
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into Parent (name, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Child (name, parent_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: delete from Child where parent_id=?
Hibernate: insert into Child (name, parent_id) values (?, ?)

SELECT * FROM CHILD
    NAME, PARENT_ID
    child2, 1
SELECT * FROM PARENT
    ID, NAME
    1, parent
```

Comment: I do not have the Hibernate version you have, but I would suggest you try `manager.remove(child);` instead of `child.parent = null;`. Maybe you have to add `manager.clear();` after the flush.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I use `remove(child)` only, I get `deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)` even if I null the associations. If I `detach(child)` as well, Hibernate tries to insert and I get the unique constraint violation.

Comment: Can you show the DDL (create table  incl. keys, foreign keys, ..) that has been created ?

Comment: The SQL generation and final table state is now added to the question

Comment: The only other way I can think of is to `detach` the entities from the manager, delete and insert child using `createNativeQuery`
and `refresh` them - but then using `flush` is much easier, so why not stick to it ? By the way: The generated DDL looks exactly like Inheritance mapping using the [Joined table strategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-joined-table) and there deletion of Child must not be possible.

Comment: I started experimenting with `@MapsId` after reading the suggestion from [Bidirectional @OneToOne lazy association](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one-bidirectional-lazy). Seems like my best options are to overwrite or remove and flush

Answer (score 0):

I found that one way to solve this problem is to create the new `Child` object desired, correctly reference the `Parent` with this new `Child` object, then set the new `Child` object's id to be that of the parent, and finally then merge the `Child` object using the `EntityManager`.

The following is Groovy code, so null checks and syntax differ slightly from Java.  this is untested code but is identical to what i use in a similar situation.

```
//load the Parent class
Parent _parent = entityManager.find(Parent.class, 1L)

//create a new Child object, passing in ref to parent
Child child = new Child()
child.parent = _parent
//check if child already exists with _parent
if(!_parent.child){
    //no child is currently associated, so associate and persist
    _parent.child = child
    //persist the child, which owns the relationship
    entityManager.persist(child)
}else{
    //update existing, set the id since they are OneToOne
    child.id = _parent.id
    _parent.child = child
    //merge the child
    entityManager.merge(_parent.child)
}
```